# OpenShift: MySQL in scalable app

Tags: mysql, openshift

I created a new scalable app with JbossAS7. Once that was created, added MySql cartridge. But when I login to the gear using SSH, I'm not able to see mysql directory. Also when trying to use sqlplus, command not found error is thrown.

I also  tried to connect to the DataBase using a simple Java application using JDBC. Valuse in the Openshift environment variables were used. Got a connection time-out exception.

Am I missing something basic here?

Thanks,
Swad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a scalable app, mysql is located on a child gear.  If all you want is to get a mysql shell, you van run `mysql` from your ssh session to the head gear.

*Have to run now - I'll supply more detail later.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` is located in `/var/lib/*your ssh username*/mysql`.

If you want to connect to the mysql server from your computer, you should also use an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Previously i used a non-scalable app. Then I was able to view ~/mysql. sqlplus command was also working. But when I created a scalable app, Im not able to view ~/mysql dir.